# Standard notation for an unevaluated expression

Tags: functions, notation

It's standard to denote an unevaluated function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ simply by "$f$" (that is, the function itself, rather than its value at a given point).

But say we have an expression such as $z e^{az}$. Is there a standard way to denote the implied function (i.e. without variables), rather than simply the function evaluated at $z$? I suppose one option would be $(z\mapsto z e^{az})$, but this is mildly unwieldy.

For example if I wanted to express the Laplace transform of the function implied by $ze^{az}$, it wouldn't be quite right to write $\mathcal{L}(ze^{az})$ because represents a number "$ze^{az}$" rather than the function itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The notation $x \mapsto \text{stuff}$ is the shortest I've seen used in maths for explicitly defining an [anonymous function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function). If you want to be more concise (e.g., like with $\mathcal{L}(ze^{az})$ instead of $\mathcal{L}(z \mapsto ze^{az})$), you just have to trust that the reader has enough context to understand what you mean.

Comment: Another possible notation is to use a designated symbol, like $(-)$ to indicate "where the variable has to go". For example one could denote with $e^{a (-)}$ the function $x \mapsto e^{ax}$. That notation works particularly well when making a two variable function into a single variable one by fixing one of the arguments. Like $f(x,-)$ for $y \mapsto f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 3):

As @parsiad comments, there is a standard for "anonymous" functions, namely $z\to ze^{az}$ in this case. But/and, yes, people mostly will understand that "$ze^{az}$" means that function.

Unsurprisingly, in some cases there can be ambiguities, so more needs to be said to set the context adequately for your readers/audience. :)

Comment: @parsiad said $z\mapsto ze^{az}$ with `\mapsto` ($\mapsto$) rather than `\to` ($\to$)

Comment: I know that there is some preference for $\mapsto" rather than "\to", but, for me, context is usually sufficient to distinguish... and, for personal aesthetic reasons, I don't like the left end of the "mapsto" symbol. :)